# Adding Baked Audio Rotation to a pre-existing rotation

Tags: animation, transforms, keyframes, audio

I'm making a music video, and I would like the rotation of the below plane to be accelerated, but not absolutely determined, by the audio keyframe bake.

In other words, I would like the plane to rotate continuously in one direction, and have this rotation be accelerated by audio form.

So every time the audio spikes, the continuous rotation of the plane accelerates, then returns to a standard rate of rotation.

As it is, just baking the f-curve, the plane just wiggles slightly between twitches between 5.9° and 0°, which is not a very interesting effect.

[image]

Comment: Not going to add an answer. But I think creating two actions (*audio_action* and *rotation_action*) then combining them in the NLA leaves enough control.

Answer (score 1):

In Bake Sound settings (when selecting sound file) click on additive option:

[image]

Comment: @WebbHinton Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you". Comments are meant for requesting clarification, leaving constructive criticism, or adding relevant but minor additional information – not for socializing. If you want to say "thank you," vote on or accept that person's answer. https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers